# How to I re run a function after I start node js app

Tags: node.js, linux, ssh

I have sample code below for my big project app.js

```
function ajax()
{
console.log("data from server test");
}

 module.exports ={
        ajax
    }

var test = require("./file");
test.ajax();
```

I run the app via command line like following

```
node app
```

Its starting and its printing

```
>data from server test
```

How do I call the function `ajax()` again from terminal without restarting the node js app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) module to do this. The following code will present the user with a prompt, whose input you can handle accordingly:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const test = require("./file");

const readInput = () => {
    rl.question("Please choose an action:\n"
        + "a) Action a\n"
        + "b) Exit\n"
        , line => {    
            switch (line) {
                case "a":
                    test.ajax();
                    break;
                case "b":
                    return rl.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("No such action. Please try again...");
            }
            readInput();
        });
};

readInput();
```

Comment: @Gracie: Any feedback?